# Adding date to the name of a gwl file

Tags: vba

I am trying to add the date to the name of a file to make it more recognizable so anyone can find the file they are looking for based off the date and time. However, whenever I add the date the file cuts off and saves it as a "file" instead of a .gwl like I want it to. Gwl is just a text file with gwl on the end. I attached an image of what I want to happen as the gwl file should have the date but instead it just saves itself as a zero byte file.

```
Sub Write2File() 'Makes the text file including the commands for the Tecan
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim dt As String
    Dim MyString As String
    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm")
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & dt & "Worklist.gwl" For Append As #1
    Sheets("WorkList Generator").Select
    Sheets("WorkList Generator").Range("A2").Select
    While ActiveCell <> ""
    For ColNum = 1 To 11
            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then MyString = MyString & ActiveCell & ";" Else MyString = MyString & ActiveCell & ";"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            DoEvents
    Next ColNum
        MyString = Left(MyString, Len(MyString) - 2)
            If MyString = "W;;;;;;;;;" Then
                Print #1, "W"
            Else
                Print #1, MyString
            End If
        MyString = ""
        Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Select
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Close #1
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it was the colon I had in the hh:mm that was causing it to think it was going into a file directory. I changed it to an underscore and it worked just fine